# Xamarin Forms & Plugin.MediaManager - How to play 2 videos side by side

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, plugins, android-video-player

At my Xamarin.Forms app with Plugin.MediaManager I need to play two videos side by side but I am not discovering how to.
Using the Grid with 2 columns and 2 stack panels I am able to see the first video but not the second one once at MainActivity there is only one  CrossMediaManager.Current.Init(this). The question is how to "init" the second video and play it?
I am porting my WPF app to Xamarin Forms that is quite new for me I confess, so XAML is welcome also.

Comment: take a look at MediaElement - not sure if it allows side by side, but it might be worth trying.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/mediaelement

Comment: @Luis Why you want to play two video side by side? Can you consider to play a sequence of media items, I think it is easy to watch.

Comment: the idea is to compare golf or tennis swings. I want to to play both videos frame by frame and compare my swing with a professional player swing

Comment: at this moment, as @Jason  suggested, I am using MediaElement and I have already videos running side by side. Now I must see if MediaElement events and methods are appropriate for my needs

Comment: side by side view is easy but cannot get frame by frame play. From what I understand, reading just now development at Android Studio posts, there is a key frame and delta frames to be decoded, so it seems quite complicated if no library for Xamarin Forms exist for this. But I am searching now for more information

Comment: For the moment I followed another quite tough path. I installed Android Studio that is quite inferior to Visual Studio and quite confusing to use, but the idea is running a sample that works and after that comeback to (the excellent) Visual Studio with the steps necessary to make  frame by frame play. It is quite frustrating to work with AS so a lot of time wasted.